# Set value dependent on whether object's property value is 0, 1 or 2

Tags: javascript

This code checks whether an object property is truthy or falsy. If truthy, it shows this element: &#10004, else: &#10008

```
const w1 = `
<p class = "center border2">${presenceObj.data().week1 ? '&#10004' : '&#10008'} </p>
`;
```

But I want to check the element's value, which is 0 or 1 or 2. If 0 show :&#10004, if 1 show: &#10008, if 2 show: &#9989

Comment: I'm not sure what `presenceObj.data().week1` is (true/false and numbers are different things -- is it possible that it can take on all of those values or... ?), but why not use an array or object to look up the value you want? Does `["&#10004", "10008", "&#9989"][presenceObj.data().week1]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic part can use an array literal for the different colors, and use the dynamic value as index for that array:

```
`${['&#10004','&#10008', '&#9989'][presenceObj.data().week1]}`
```

Comment: Working well. Thanks!